# How to make a script wait for a specific key press - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I want the script to wait for me to press E again to finish time.time()

```
import keyboard
import time
from playsound import playsound
import msvcrt as m



while True:

    if keyboard.is_pressed("e"):
        start = time.time()
        wait()# I want the program to wait for me to press E again
        end = time.time()

        time_lapsed = end - start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `keyboard.wait()`, this wait function will wait until hotkey pressed (in our case 'e')...

```py
while True:
    start = time.time()
    keyboard.wait("e")
    end = time.time()
    time_lapsed = end - start
```

In case you don't want to start with fresh time every loop, you can move `start=time.time()` out side of `while` loop